# calculate total score using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays, dom-events

I am creating a quiz. My quiz is divided in 4 parts and I have 50 questions total. There is a score and question counter, but I want to continue the question counter and score when the quiz jumped to the next part and I need a total score at the end. I am not expert in Javascript. I am just a beginner. So Please help me with the solution.

```js
const choices = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("choice-text"));
const progressText = document.getElementById("progressText");
const scoreText = document.getElementById("score");
const progressBarFull = document.getElementById("progressBarFull");
let currentQuestion = {};
let acceptingAnswers = false;
let score = 0;
let questionCounter = 0;
let availableQuesions = [];

let questions = [
  {
    question: "Inside which HTML element do we put the JavaScript??",
    choice1: "<script>",
    choice2: "<javascript>",
    choice3: "<js>",
    choice4: "<scripting>",
    answer: 1
  },
  {
    question:
      "What is the correct syntax for referring to an external script called 'xxx.js'?",
    choice1: "<script href='xxx.js'>",
    choice2: "<script name='xxx.js'>",
    choice3: "<script src='xxx.js'>",
    choice4: "<script file='xxx.js'>",
    answer: 3
  },
  {
    question: " How do you write 'Hello World' in an alert box?",
    choice1: "msgBox('Hello World');",
    choice2: "alertBox('Hello World');",
    choice3: "msg('Hello World');",
    choice4: "alert('Hello World');",
    answer: 4
  }
];

//CONSTANTS
const CORRECT_BONUS = 10;
const MAX_QUESTIONS = 3;

startGame = () => {
  questionCounter = 0;
  score = 0;
  availableQuesions = [...questions];
  getNewQuestion();
};

getNewQuestion = () => {
  if (availableQuesions.length === 0 || questionCounter >= MAX_QUESTIONS) {
    localStorage.setItem("mostRecentScore", score);
    //go to the end page
    return window.location.assign("/end.html");
  }
  questionCounter++;
  progressText.innerText = `Question ${questionCounter}/${MAX_QUESTIONS}`;
  //Update the progress bar
  progressBarFull.style.width = `${(questionCounter / MAX_QUESTIONS) * 100}%`;

  const questionIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * availableQuesions.length);
  currentQuestion = availableQuesions[questionIndex];
  question.innerText = currentQuestion.question;

  choices.forEach(choice => {
    const number = choice.dataset["number"];
    choice.innerText = currentQuestion["choice" + number];
  });

  availableQuesions.splice(questionIndex, 1);
  acceptingAnswers = true;
};

choices.forEach(choice => {
  choice.addEventListener("click", e => {
    if (!acceptingAnswers) return;

    acceptingAnswers = false;
    const selectedChoice = e.target;
    const selectedAnswer = selectedChoice.dataset["number"];

    const classToApply =
      selectedAnswer == currentQuestion.answer ? "correct" : "incorrect";

    if (classToApply === "correct") {
      incrementScore(CORRECT_BONUS);
    }

    selectedChoice.parentElement.classList.add(classToApply);

    setTimeout(() => {
      selectedChoice.parentElement.classList.remove(classToApply);
      getNewQuestion();
    }, 1000);
  });
});

incrementScore = num => {
  score += num;
  scoreText.innerText = score;
};

startGame();
```

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Quick Quiz - Play</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="game.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div id="game" class="justify-center flex-column">
        <div id="hud">
          <div id="hud-item">
            <p id="progressText" class="hud-prefix">
              Question
            </p>
            <div id="progressBar">
              <div id="progressBarFull"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div id="hud-item">
            <p class="hud-prefix">
              Score
            </p>
            <h1 class="hud-main-text" id="score">
              0
            </h1>
          </div>
        </div>
        <h2 id="question">What is the answer to this questions?</h2>
        <div class="choice-container">
          <p class="choice-prefix">A</p>
          <p class="choice-text" data-number="1">Choice 1</p>
        </div>
        <div class="choice-container">
          <p class="choice-prefix">B</p>
          <p class="choice-text" data-number="2">Choice 2</p>
        </div>
        <div class="choice-container">
          <p class="choice-prefix">C</p>
          <p class="choice-text" data-number="3">Choice 3</p>
        </div>
        <div class="choice-container">
          <p class="choice-prefix">D</p>
          <p class="choice-text" data-number="4">Choice 4</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="game.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please add specific question that you want to resolve.

Comment: What's the problem with the current code? Does it not increment the score?

Comment: @Asutosh I want make this quiz into 4 parts and the scoring and question counter must continue during each part.

Comment: @bluejayke This code stands can be used for only one part of the quiz. after completing this part of the quiz i need to start another part of the quiz without losing previous score and question counter.

Comment: @dony but how are you starting the other part, are you opening a new page or just showing anther div that is hidden?

Comment: @bluejayke by opening a new page

Answer (score 0):

If your quiz contains or lasts throughout multiple pages and you want to communicate between those pages then you can use `localStorage`

When you're done with one part of the quiz, or even if you're not, just set the value of localStorage to the score, and read it on page load, or in general

```
incrementScore = num => {
   if(typeof(localStorage.getItem("score") != "number"))
       localStorage.setItem("score", 0)
  score = localStorage.getItem("score")
  score += num;
  scoreText.innerText = score;
};
```